# Use git commit history to find project hot-spots?

Tags: git

I'm joining a new project with a long and storied commit history, and I'd like to use that history to show me the hot-spots in the project: the files that have been most commonly (and most recently) edited.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid writing more than a few lines of script (ruby, python, javascript; doesn't matter which).

Anybody know of a one-liner that can rank git project files according to their activity in a commit history?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gource/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this one-liner to print the top 100 most frequently changed files:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sed '/^\s*$/d' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -100
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a `sed '/^\s*$/d'` pipe between the git and the sort command, so we don't count newlines as "changed files".

Comment: The sort pipe did not work on windows had to change to this `git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort /R | head -100`